# Call jQuery function from variable name directly

Tags: jquery

Maybe it is not possible what I want to do, I just hoping. If not, there is no problem and I will write a class. I just want to avoid that.

Of course, I tried to search for answers on net. I found something here on SO and on jQuery forum. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483553/jquery-using-a-variable-as-a-function-name), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588307/calling-a-jquery-function-named-in-a-variable), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript).

But what I want to do this in a different way:

I want to call it directly, and **I do not want to use eval**!

What I thought to do something like this

```
var target = '#id';
var method = 'removeClass';
var className = 'classToShow';

$(taget).method(className);
```

I am getting this:

```
TypeError: $(...).method is not a function
[Learn More]
```

So is there a way to do this?

Comment: Side note: never use reserved keywords like `class`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `jQuery` (and therefore the `$` variable) refer to an object, you can use bracket notation, like this:

```
$(target)[method](className);
```

```js
var target = '#id';
var method = 'removeClass';
var className = 'classToShow';
$(target)[method](className);
```

```css
.classToShow {
  color: red; /* this colour will be removed */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id" class="classToShow">Foo bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did it correct in general. But your variable is not named `$id`, it is `target`. And `class` is a registered name in javascript, so you can't use it.

The method can be select as a property of `$()`.

```
var target = '#id';
var method ='removeClass';
var myClass = 'classToShow';

$(target)[method](myClass);
```

Comment: You are right, I am not wrote it and test it, just type here. I will fix it.